# @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, annotations

I have a JPA entity with a property set as

```
@ManyToOne
@Column(name="LicenseeFK")
private Licensee licensee;
```

But when I deploy on JBoss 6 the application throws an error saying:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property
```

I use Hibernate 3.5 as the JPA 2.0 implementation.

What should I use to reference the foreign key column?

Comment: Maybe removing the @ManyToOne annotation resolves your problem.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="LicenseeFK")
private Licensee licensee;
```

Comment: But why? Any explanation to that?

Comment: @OndrejTokar maybe because You use `@ManyToOne` on this, and `"mappedBy"` on the other side (class), which means that this column (named `"LicenseeFK"`) is a foreign key, and therefore a joined column.
So, it is a joinedColumn with name `"LicenseeFK"`. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @OndrejTokar what about go to docs? you have the annotations names...

Answer (score 11):

### `@Column`

The JPA `@Column` annotation is for basic entity attributes, like `String`, `Integer`, `Date`.

So, if the entity attribute name differs from the underlying column name, then you need to use the `@Column` annotation to specify the column name explicitly, like this:

```
@Column(name="created_on")
private LocalDate createdOn;
```

### `@JoinColumn`

The `@JoinColumn` annotation is used to customize a Foreign Key column name, and it can only be used with an entity association.

So, in your case, because you are using a `@ManyToOne` association, you need to use `@JoinColumn`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchTYpe.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="LicenseeFK")
private Licensee licensee;
```

Notice that we set the `fetch` attribute to `FetchType.LAZY` because, by default, [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) is used, and that's a terrible strategy.

Answer (score 9):

Using `@JoinColumn` and `@Column` together will result in the same error.
Change it to only use: **`@JoinColumn`** to fix it.

Comment: Your answer is quite confusing. You cannot use \@Column with \@ManyToOne point.

Answer (score 2):

In my case @VaishaliKulkarni's answer was helpful to identify the problem.

I missed to write field for @Column annotion and it effected on next field.

```
@Column(name = "account_id")
// I forgot to write field here

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```

So, I was getting exception at "customer" field.