# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig'

Tags: spring, tomcat, jwt

I try to create auth via jwt token with this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-1/

I cannot resolve this problem:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.easythings.battleship.BattleshipApplicationKt.main(BattleshipApplication.kt:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customUserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#58ec8271' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#58ec8271': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: com.easythings.battleship.model.Game.board
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    internal var customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService? = null

    @Autowired
    private val unauthorizedHandler: JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint? = null

    @Bean
    fun jwtAuthenticationFilter(): JwtAuthenticationFilter {
        return JwtAuthenticationFilter()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    public override fun configure(authenticationManagerBuilder: AuthenticationManagerBuilder?) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder!!
                .userDetailsService<UserDetailsService>(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
class CustomUserDetailsService : UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    internal var userRepository: UserRepository? = null

    @Transactional
    @Throws(UsernameNotFoundException::class)
    override fun loadUserByUsername(usernameOrEmail: String): UserDetails {
        // Let people login with either username or email
        val user = userRepository!!.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail)
                .orElseThrow {
                    UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username or email : $usernameOrEmail")
                }

        return UserPrincipal.create(user)
    }

    // This method is used by JWTAuthenticationFilter
    @Transactional
    fun loadUserById(id: Long?): UserDetails {
        val user = userRepository!!.findById(id!!)
                .orElseThrow { UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : $id") }

        return UserPrincipal.create(user)
    }
}
```

I'm new in spring and I don't know what is wrong.
My springBootVersion is '2.1.2.RELEASE'. What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not
>   allowed on a @ManyToOne property:
>   com.easythings.battleship.model.Game.board

It seems that you have put `@Column` annotation on your manyToOne field in entity class. Use `@JoinColumn` instead. (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121485/columns-not-allowed-on-a-manytoone-property) and [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association))