# Hibernate ignoring @JoinColumn value for @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a hibernate code which was working well with the default join column value, but when I change the join column value to as desired by application convention it started breaking.
Before: `@JoinColumn(name="state_name") List<City> cities;`
After : `@JoinColumn(name="state_nm") List<City> cities;`

The problem is hibernate is creating the given column `state_nm` in the table but it is not using it. The table output is below.

```
mysql> select * from city;
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| name       | population | state_name | state_nm |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| BayArea    | 7200000    | CA         | NULL     |
| Detriot    | 630000     | MI         | NULL     |
| LA         | 3900000    | CA         | NULL     |
| Miami      | 466000     | FL         | NULL     |
| RapidsCity | 188000     | MI         | NULL     |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you see, hibernate has still gone ahead and created the `state_name` column and as a result joins are returning null result.

```
2019-09-09 19:59:14.807 DEBUG 7812 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table city (
       name varchar(255) not null,
        population varchar(255),
        state_name varchar(255),
        state_nm varchar(255),
        primary key (name)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2019-09-09 19:59:16.158 DEBUG 7812 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL
```

The Java Model Entities are below:

```
@Table(name="state")
@Entity
public class State { 

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    @Column(name="population") 
    String population;  

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_nm") 
    List<City> cities;

    @ManyToOne //(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) // don't use cascade all with ManyToOne, atleast for now
    Country country; 
    getters/setters

@Table(name="city")
@Entity
public class City {

        @Id
        @Column(name="name")
        String name;

        @Column(name="population")
        String population;

        @ManyToOne 
        State state;
        getters/setters
```

Any hint's on why this behavior.

code can be found on branch "joincolumn_issue": 
https://github.com/samshers/graphql-hibernate/tree/joincolumn_issue

Edit: This question is different. In the first place it is not about @Column or @JoinColumn, it is about being able to give a user defined name to the @JoinColumn. Hibernate provides three ways of doing OneToMany Mapping. The approach posted in this question can be considered as one way. The answer from @Sterconium can be seen as second approach where mappedBy is used. Next there is a @JoinTable based approach. So, Here I am looking for solution based on first approach where I can define a join column name as per application demand. So this question is no way related to the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121485/columns-not-allowed-on-a-manytoone-property) question.

Comment: @Moderator, please unmark this question as duplicate or "might be answered here" as this is entirely different approach from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

On class `State`, replace

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="state_nm") 
List<City> cities;
```

with

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "state")
List<City> cities;
```

On class `City`, replace

```
@ManyToOne 
State state;
```

With

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="state_nm")
State state;
```

Which I guess can be summarized in

- Define the relationship on `City` instead of `State` (not sure about the terminology, I'm new to hibernate);
- Use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column`

By doing so the create city query logged becomes:

```
2019-09-09 17:49:37.821 DEBUG 3180 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 

    create table city (
       name varchar(255) not null,
        population varchar(255),
        state_nm varchar(255),
        primary key (name)
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

And the constrain logged is:

```
2019-09-09 17:49:39.033 DEBUG 3180 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 

    alter table city 
       add constraint FKnpj8mmul6j6kcl7p90bdo1gj7 
       foreign key (state_nm) 
       references state (name)
```

I referred to [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121485/columns-not-allowed-on-a-manytoone-property)

Hope I helped

Comment: your solution is right and work's. It's based on using `mappedBy` . Hibernate provides three ways of doing OneToMany Mapping. The approach posted in this question can be considered as first way. The answer from @Sterconium (you) can be seen as second approach where mappedBy is used. Next there is a @JoinTable based approach. So, Here I am looking for solution based on first approach where I can define a join column name as per application demand. Tying to explore the 3 approaches, so I can understand if there is any limitation defined by hibernate, so I know when to use which.

Comment: moving my code to use mappedBy as this seems to works in consistent manner than other approaches. +1,